Is a $2\times 2$ block matrix with PSD matrices on the off-diagonal and diagonal matrices on diagonal PSD?
I am working with a model where the covariance matrix is of the form
$$\boldsymbol\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}A&B^\top\\ B&C\end{pmatrix},$$
where $A=\sigma^2\mathcal I$, $C=\tau^2\mathcal I$, and $B$ is nonnegative definite. $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all $p\times p$ matrices. In my model, $\sigma^2$ and $\tau^2$ are parameters to be estimated and $B$ has a known covariance structure. Fitting the model requires the inverting the matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma$.
Is it necessarily the case that $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is also nonnegative definite?

See Schur complement.

For a counterexample with $p=2$, let
$$
\boldsymbol\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}A&B^\top\\B&C\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A=\sigma^2\mathcal I,\;C=\tau^2\mathcal I,\;0 < \sigma,\tau < 1$,$\;$and
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}b&1\\1&b\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $b\ge 2$.

For an even simpler counterexample with $p=1$, let
$$
\boldsymbol\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&b\\b&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $b > 1$.
